# Can't connect to Ubuntu server over Filezilla SSH

Tags: ssh, sftp, filezilla

bit of a newby here.

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a cloud server for a project and I can't connect to it as root or sudo user with Filezilla. I'm using the SSH/SFTP connection option. At first it said that the connection timed out, and when disabling the timeout FZ just says it couldn't connect to the server. Things I've tried:

1. I've pinged the server's public IP on Windows cmd and it gave back the packets normally.
2. I've set up a pair of keys using this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04
3. I've added a rule to ufw to accept SSH.
4. I've added the lines `PasswordAuthentication yes` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` to the sshd config file.

I'm a little bit at a loss of how to continue and establish the connection successfully. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! I managed to set this by trying the connection from another port. Why this is the case I honestly don't know, I don't remember setting the port to another one, but whatever. Thanks anyway!